# CodeIgniter select data and count

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

Within CodeIgniter, I'm doing a select, retrieving some blogposts. But I also want the total reactions of a blogpost with the count() function. But when I'm doing this, it only returns one record.

Example:

```
    $this->db->select('idee_id, titel, omschrijving, type, top_idee, tbl_users.foto as user_foto');
    $this->db->from('tbl_idee');
    $this->db->join('tbl_types', 'tbl_idee.type_id = tbl_types.type_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_users', 'tbl_idee.user_id = tbl_users.user_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_comments', 'tbl_users.user_id = tbl_comments.user_id');
    $this->db->order_by('post_datum', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $q = $this->db->get();
```

Now I only get the blogposts without total reactions of one blogpost.
How can I fix this? With a select in a select.?

Thanks

Comment: Better do it with another query, also you can you union select

Comment: did you try `$this->db->group_by("idee_id");` ?

Comment: -safrov: what is an UNION select? Something like a join? Because CI doesn't support union select. Then I to write a custom query, correct? -tpaksu: no, in the select, i need to add count("reactions"), but then I only get one record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make the database select the number of each blog post's comments

```
$this->db->select('idee_id, titel, omschrijving, type, top_idee,
      tbl_users.foto as user_foto, COUNT(*) AS comments',FALSE);
```

note the second parameter, it prevents codeigniter from parsing the `COUNT()` function

you are retrieving data from a blog post together with its comments, so you need to `GROUP BY` the data which makes a blogpost unique:

```
$this->db->group_by('idee_id,titel, omschrijving, type,
      top_idee, tbl_users.foto');
```

the rest of your query should be correct

Answer (score 0):

If you know the raw SQL to get you the data you need. Your best bet might be to do:

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

This way you have the freedom to construct your SQL yourself without using CI db methods. I hope this helps...

Comment: But the problem is, do I need to write 2 different query's or can I just write the sql in one query?

Comment: you should be able to write in single query. grouping comments by post_id should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks, but the solutions has been found :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check all your tables. check that all have multiple records because your are joining them with simple join query. if one of them is less records than other. then user left or right join query.

else for your result.

```
$q = $this->db->get();
return $q->result_array();
```

and for counting the records

```
$q = $this->db->get();
$count = $q->num_rows();
```

It will counts your records as well.